# Seven Totally Unrelated Words

Tags: word

Whatever you do, don't try to find a common link between the following list of words. There isn't one, I promise. And don't try to find a secret hidden word. There's not one of those, either.

> $along, soothe, haunt, remain, leap, candle, aurist$

Like I said, nothing to find here... just move on...

---

**Clarification:** All of my nonsensical denying is just for fun. The entire puzzle could theoretically be solved with just the seven words and nothing else, but I'm a sucker for some silly exposition.

Comment: Did you post this to see if the community can find out something out of nothing???

Comment: @Anachor nah, I prefer for my puzzles to stay riiiight on the line between cruel and downright mean, and I'm afraid that would push it way over!

Comment: Well, I was going to try something with antonyms since you're definitely not giving any hints with your puzzle wording, but *candle* obviously doesn't have any.

Comment: @IanMacDonald What about _cannotdle_?

Comment: Does this non-existent secret word relate to the seven words above themeatically?

Comment: Hey, what if you read the words backwards ? For example, along become gnola, that mean ... absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Revulai nothing relates to these seven words thematically. They're unrelated. (Really.) BUT, when you can figure out *how* to make them related, you'll find that the hidden word certainly does relate to them thematically.

Comment: @Therandomguy, 'gnola' is shockingly close to helpful in solving this one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are all

> anagrams of countries with the first letter removed.

along

> Angola

soothe

> Lesotho

haunt

> Bhutan

remain

> Armenia

leap

> Nepal

candle

> Iceland

aurist

> Austria

So the word that links them is

> Albania

Comment: Why, yes they are. Well done, my fine fellow!

Comment: If I might ask, which one did you find first?

Comment: @BaileyM I saw your comment about gnola being very close and then Nepal and Armenia jumped out at me. I looked at a list of World countries to fill in the rest, but it was very quick once I confirmed that the missing letters were in the correct order.

Comment: I was SO CLOSE ... argh. "Along" is an anagram of Golan [Heights], so I was looking for more anagrams of place names in the Middle East :-P

Comment: I love how my random comment became a hint :D

Answer (score 2):

I almost believed you that there was no common link. And was almost off on my way to other puzzles.

### But...

I wasn't going to fall for your trickery. And these words that you so loudly proclaimed were common unrelated words, they are all cut from the same cloth. They are tricksters, dropping away a part of their identity, changing a bit of their remaining traits, and blending in with the populace without suspicion.

Your plan was good, far too good. *But I'm better...* And I've unmasked your hidden thugs.

> In each word, drop a letter, and then replace one other letter to get a different word. 
> along-n#r(l,g)=agog 
> soothe-e#r(s,b)=booth 
> haunt-a#r(t,k)=hunk 
> remain-a#r(m,s)=resin 
> leap-p#r(a,d)=led 
> candle-l#r(e,y)=candy 
> aurist-u#r(t,e)=arise
>  The minus sign subtracts the specified letter, whereas the #r operation replaces the specified letter with another letter.

Comment: This seems far too generic - it could apply to way too many words. For example, all of the words in the previous sentence could turn into: The, sums, or, of, genera, a, hold, ably, I, by, on, mat, cord.

Comment: Aye, this is more generic than the "property" I'm definitely not looking for. Plus you have not provided a hidden word, which is good, because there is none. If I were you, I would certainly not continue to study the letters and possible permutations (as you have been), since there is nothing to find.